# How to write .htaccess file code to change old url to new url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I want to rewrite my url using .htaccess. My old url is `http://gametesting.in/infocomstudios/gamedetails.php?id=2` and I need to change it as the following `http://gametesting.in/infocomstudios/demopage.html`. What code is used in my .htaccess. I tried with the following code:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^gamedetails\.php demopage.html [L,R]
```

But I got an error:

> The requested URL /home/gamet/public_html/infocomstudios/demopage.html
>   was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request.

And my new url becomes: `http://gametesting.in/home/gamet/public_html/infocomstudios/demopage.html?id=2`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This is a standard 404 error. The server can't find the new page. Might have to do with ?id=2 not being acceptable on html-files.

Comment: @Linkan thanks for your comment.But actually I wantto rewrite my url.so there is no need to create that html file

Comment: The way the rules are written, you send people coming to gamedetails.php?id=2 to demopage.html, which has to exist for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just adjusted you Rule a bit to save Path and Query String:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)gamedetails\.php(.*) $1demopage.html$2 [L,R]
```

Tested it online [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Thanku @copynpaste..Same error is occured while using your code.Any other solutions for this issue?I am first time  in .htaccess datz y

Comment: Ah don't really read that error sry. Are you sure that file exists on exact this location? And the ServerUser (f.e. www-data on Apache) has access to it?

Comment: actually i have no page with name **demopage.html** when I call this **http://gametesting.in/infocomstudios/gamedetails.php?id=2** then only display the url as following **http://gametesting.in/infocomstudios/demopage.html**

Comment: You just want to have demopage.html in the url as replacement to gamedetailts.php?id=2 but want to keep the content?

Comment: yup..but my original url is **gametesting.in/infocomstudios/gamedetails.php?id=2** and I want to replace it as **gametesting.in/infocomstudios/demopage.html**

Comment: You have to handle this is your backend logic. You should create a route `demopage.html` and handle in your php code to call the code from gamedetails

Answer (score 0):

Try this i haven't tested it please tell if tell if error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^infocomstudios/demopage.html$ infocom/gamedetails.php?id=2 [L]
```